# Webservices feature pack is installed but RAD says 'it is not installed'

Tags: websphere, websphere-6.1, ibm-rad

When I run this command:

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\bin>versionInfo.bat
```

The output is:

```
WVER0010I: Copyright (c) IBM Corporation 2002, 2005; All rights reserved.
WVER0012I: VersionInfo reporter version 1.15.4.3, dated 11/12/08

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IBM WebSphere Application Server Product Installation Status Report
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Report at date and time November 24, 2011 2:34:40 EST PM

Installation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Product Directory        C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61
Version Directory        C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\properties\version
DTD Directory            C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\properties\version\dtd
Log Directory            C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\logs
Backup Directory         C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\properties\version\nif\backup
TMP Directory            C:\DOCUME~1\kguha\LOCALS~1\Temp

Product List
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EJB3                     installed
BASE                     installed
WEB2FEP                  installed
WEBSERVICES              installed

Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                     WebSphere Application Server Version 6.1 Feature Pack for EJB 3.0
Version                  6.1.0.29
ID                       EJB3
Build Level              cf290949.04
Build Date               12/12/09

Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                     IBM WebSphere Application Server
Version                  6.1.0.29
ID                       BASE
Build Level              cf290949.16
Build Date               12/11/09

Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                     Web 2.0 Feature Pack
Version                  1.0.0.1
ID                       WEB2FEP
Build Level              web20835.6
Build Date               8/28/08

Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                     WebServices Feature Pack
Version                  6.1.0.29
ID                       WEBSERVICES
Build Level              cf290949.05
Build Date               12/12/09

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
End Installation Status Report
```

But when I open up RAD and deploy some web service projects on WAS 6.1, it says that `please install webservices feature pack` although as it is seen from the list, the feature pack is present already.

When I try to augment an existing profile with installed feature pack, only ejb3.0 feature pack is available to me to augment and not the webservices feature pack. What should I do? I would like to avoid a fresh uninstall/reinstall of WAS at all costs

Comment: Is it possible to create a totally new profile with both feature packs? Maybe the augmenting just won't function properly.

Comment: I can create a new profile. But while creating a new profile, will it automatically include the feature packs? There is no option to explicitly include them when you create a new profile

Comment: Well, you never know. I've had similar troubles with WAS previously, although I used only the EJB3 pack. But it's at least worth a shot to try. Create a new profile and try to augment that one. It might just be that the old profile can't be augmented fully and the new one will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you resolved this, but I just went through it myself, so I wanted to share what I learned. The Web Services Feature Pack cannot be added to an existing profile; a new one has to be created. The EJB 3.0 Feature Pack, however, can augment an existing profile, including one with the Web Services Feature Pack in it.

So what worked for us was to create a new profile from the Web Services Feature Pack template, then augment that profile with the EJB 3.0 template.

Comment: Just now faced issue, and got it resolved from your comments. Here is link i followed to resolve the issue - [RAD Profile Creation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21263551)